# Why does my Excel require pipes instead of commas in formulas now?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm using Excel 2013 on Windows 7 x64. Yesterday, I could write formulas using commas, like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1), "num", "not num")
```

but today, I have to enter the formula using pipes, like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1)|"num"|"not num")
```

I don't recall installing any updates, but did an update change this, or did I accidentally tweak a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely issue:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2853427

> When entering a formula an error will occur if trying to use a symbol that is not the default 'list separator' in the Windows Regional settings.

The KB article tells you what to do to solve the problem. In the process you will almost certainly discover what setting or option got changed and where ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of Windows/Excel the argument delimiter can be changed. See:
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/768848-formulas-require-pipe-instead-of-comma.html
https://www.excelcommand.com/excel-help/excel-how-to.php?i=59586

Briefly:

> From the Windows Start button:
> Control_Panel.Region_and_Language.Formats tab
> Click: Additional settings...Numbers
> See if the pipe symbol is where a comma should be.
>
> I do have XP so my settings do look just a little bit different but....your suggestion made me decide to poke around and I found it!! YOU ARE MY HERO!!!!
> I am still confused how this got changed, but happy it is fixed now. The steps I took in XP are....
> Control Panel>Regional and Language Options>Clicked "Customize" on the Regional Options tab>changed the "List Separator" from a pipe to a comma.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).